# Is Google Cloud Storage indexed in search?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

If a file is placed into Google Cloud storage and made public, but a URL to the file does not exist on another webpage, does Google index it in its search results anyway?  Anyone know?

Comment: I updated your question to make it more clear that it's about search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's search index is independent of its cloud storage. Making a file public in cloud storage does not automatically index it in Google's search results.

However, asking this question leads me to believe that you're probably wondering if it's okay to make a file public and be reasonably sure that the file is not accessible to anyone. If the files are of any sensitive nature to you or your users, this is not the right solution.

If you're using GCS on a website and want to serve files securely, you might want to try the [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) option. If it's just about being indexed, you could add a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file to the root of your bucket that excludes the file from being indexed.

Comment: It's a file that is accessed by a iOS app, so the URL is never made public. It's not secret info, just something I don't want indexed.

Comment: You could add a robots.txt file in your bucket to prevent it from being indexed.

Comment: Good idea. No idea if it will help, but easy to do. Thanks.

Comment: A robots.txt work only if it is placed on root directory. And that is only possible if you're using custom domain name with google cloud storage bucket, otherwise it will be placed into sub-directory like `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/robots.txt` and it will not going to work, but with custom domain name it will be your root directory like `www.bucket-name.com/robots.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public file in Google's cloud storage, the URL to that file would have to be indexed, otherwise the servers would have no way of finding it.

The same thing happens with Google Drive. A public URL is still indexed, and is still available within the server's lookup tables, even if a hard link doesn't exist anywhere on the web.

Comment: Not sure why the file "would have to be indexed".  I just don't want someone to do a google search and find the file.  I'd like it to be like there is a robot.txt file.

Comment: Oh, well I don't know about Google cloud storage allowing for robots.txt. Your question was rather unclear. I wasn't certain where you assumed it was being indexed, but now that I see you're referring to their *search results* index, then my guess would be no. But it's a guess. 

I guarantee it's indexed somewhere. May or may not be available to the public.